# Javascript syntax error in Date object

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following function in Javascript

```
function validateDates() {
Date fromDateObj = Date.parse(GetControlDate('CalDate'));
Date toDateObj = Date.parse(GetControlDate('ToDate'));
}
```

The two lines are causing a syntax error saying 'missing ';' before statement'. I can't figure out what's causing this, if I replace those lines with a simple alert statement it works fine, so I know the issue is in those lines. Also replacing those function calls `GetControlDate('CalDate')` with an actual date string doesn't fix the issue either. Can anyone tell me what the issue is?

Comment: Changing Date by var keyword should fix your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` is not a valid datatype for a variable use a weakly typed `var`.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is weak type. all variable is "var" other than strong type in Java or C#. Hence use var instead of Date

```
function validateDates() {
    var fromDateObj = Date.parse(GetControlDate('CalDate'));
    var toDateObj = Date.parse(GetControlDate('ToDate'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't have "typed" variables.  You don't need the `Date` before the variable name, you need `var`.

Also, `Date.parse` returns an int (the UNIX timestamp), not a `Date` object.

You want:

```
function validateDates() {
    var fromDateObj = new Date(GetControlDate('CalDate'));
    var toDateObj = new Date(GetControlDate('ToDate'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `var` rather than `Date` to declare your variables:

```
function validateDates() {
    var fromDateObj = Date.parse(GetControlDate('CalDate'));
    var toDateObj = Date.parse(GetControlDate('ToDate'));
}
```

JS variables aren't fixed to a particular type of value and thus aren't declared with `Date` or `int` or whatever.